# Font validation in Karate UI automation

Tags: karate

I am using karate UI framework and in that other than locating the web elements. I have a web element which is written in itallic with font size as 20. And has location as below

Xpath= //*[@id="header"]

In karate UI automation i want to validate the font size above web element but not sure how to do it.

Can someone please assist me? Thanka in advance

Expecting: To validate the font zise and font type of web element in karate ui automation.